An integral over the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$
Let $S^{d-1}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Let $|x-y|$ denote the euclidean distance between to points $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Is there a nice expression for the following (maybe classical ?) integral,
$$
I(x,y)=\int_{t\in S^{d-1}}\frac{dt}{(|t-x||t-y|)^d},\qquad|x|<1,~|y|<1.
$$

Do you want an analytic formula or just a upper bound?

I am interested in an exact formula.
